# Fast forward and timer controls disabled in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for playing the media. It works  fine but Fast forward and timer controls disabled .I have following code:

```
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:songUrl];
    [moviePlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];   
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
      [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

I have following screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us what `songUrl` looks like, but from the symptoms, I'd guess that it refers to an HTTP URL being served without a `Content-Length` header. Because iOS can't determine the file length until it's finished reading the file, it doesn't have a length to display.

Alternatively, perhaps `songUrl` refers to an HTTP Live Streaming stream without a defined start or end time (like a live feed).

Comment: Yes you are right .My songUrl refers to the http request. But How can i specify start and end time for the song.